# Type Error using Socket communication even while decoding to byte string

Tags: python, sockets, types, typeerror

Hello I got a problem with a type error I cant get rid off. 
I have build a server named processA.py and a client processB.py
I start the server calling processA and it starts up
I start the client calling processB and it starts up
Now I input the name of the file I want to send over a socket.
The image must be in the same folder as the programms. 
You can use the sample code from below for reproducing the error.

I choose: lena.jpg

I get an error in line 15, in of my processA.py:

> sock.send("EXISTS" + str(os.path.getsize(filenameByte))) TypeError: a
>   bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

processA.py
        '''
    Created on 29 Nov 2017

```
@author: Poor Student
'''
import numpy 
import socket
import threading
import os

def RtrFile(name, sock):
    filenameByte = sock.recv(1024)
    filenameStr = filenameByte.decode('ascii')
    if os.path.isfile(filenameStr):
        sock.send("EXISTS" + str(os.path.getsize(filenameByte)))
        userResponse = sock.recv(1024)
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filenameByte, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != "":
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        sock.send("ERR")

    sock.close()

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)

    print("server started.")

    while True:
        c, addr =s.accept()
        print("client connected ip:< " + str(addr) +">")
        t = threading.Thread(target = RtrFile, args=("rtrThread",c))
        t.start()
    s.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

processB.py

```
    '''
Created on 29 Nov 2017

@author: Poor Student
'''
import socket

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host,port))

    filename = input("Filename? -> ")

    if filename != "q":
        s.send(filename.encode())
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data[:6] == "EXISTS":
            filesize = int(data[6:])
            message = input("File Exists, " +str(filesize) + "Bytes, download? (Y/N)? ->")
            if message == "Y" or message =="y":
                s.send("OK")
                f = open("new_" + filename, "wb")
                data = s.recv(1024)
                totalRecv = len(data)
                f.write(data)
                while totalRecv < filesize:
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    print("(0:.f)".format((totalRecv)/float(filesize))*100 +"done")
                print("Download Complete")
        else:
            print("File does not exists")#
    s.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. In python 3 you have allways convert your Strings to byte strings when sending them. After sending them to the receiver you have to decode them again and this must be done for the hole communication which is why the error allways shows up in the same module.

```
Process A:
'''
Created on 29 Nov 2017

@author: Happy student
'''
import numpy 
import socket
import threading
import os
from idlelib.IOBinding import encoding

def RtrFile(name, sock):
    filenameByte = sock.recv(1024)
    filenameStr = filenameByte.decode('ascii')
    print("FilenameStr",filenameStr)
    if os.path.isfile(filenameStr):
        print("Type:",type(filenameByte))
        print(os.path.getsize(filenameByte))#

        sendStr = "EXISTS" + str(os.path.getsize(filenameByte))

        #Convert the string to byte because otherwise it will not be send
        sock.send((sendStr.encode(encoding)))
        userResponse = sock.recv(1024)

        #the Responce will be received in byte and will be converted to a string to make it checkable
        userResponceStr = userResponse.decode('ascii')

        if userResponceStr[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filenameByte, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != "":
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
        else:
            print("User response not known")
    else:
        sendStr = "ERR"
        sock.send(sendStr.encode(encoding))

    sock.close()

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)

    print("server started.")

    while True:
        c, addr =s.accept()
        print("client connected ip:< " + str(addr) +">")
        t = threading.Thread(target = RtrFile, args=("rtrThread",c))
        t.start()
    s.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

processB.py

```
'''
Created on 29 Nov 2017

@author:  Happy student
'''
import socket
from idlelib.IOBinding import encoding

def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host,port))

    filename = input("Filename? -> ")

    if filename != "q":
        s.send(filename.encode())
        data = s.recv(1024)
        dataStr = data.decode('ascii')
        if dataStr[:6] == "EXISTS":
            filesize = int(dataStr[6:])
            message = input("File Exists, " +str(filesize) + "Bytes, download? (Y/N)? ->")
            if message == "Y" or message =="y":
                sendStr = "OK"
                s.send(sendStr.encode(encoding))
                #create new file new_filename and 
                f = open("new_" + filename, "wb")
                data = s.recv(1024)
                totalRecv = len(data)
                f.write(data)
                while totalRecv < filesize:
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                print("Download Complete")
            else:
                print(message +"was not noticed")
                exit()
        else:
            print("File does not exists")#
    s.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```